# Linux output console to multiple monitors

Tags: linux, console, monitor

I want to output my console application to multiple outputs, or be able to select an output. Is this possible from consoleline? The idea is run a fullscreen SDL app using the VESA driver.

SDL has a VESA output mode (vgl), I've read, so it can be started from terminal (if I'm correct) and from console (without X11).

http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=702038

I could not find a non X11 solution for this.

Comment: [Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: SDL != console. VESA != console. Presumably you mean tty with framebuffer? Because, X11 _by default_ outputs the same image to all heads, unless you configure twinview, xinerama, or even separate X servers for each head. Most likely, it is driver specific (X11 uses the display driver to get this going). So, what card are you using?

Comment: Are you programming something to accomplish this, or just configuring an existing application/OS environment?  "The idea is run a fullscreen SDL app using the VESA driver" - this sounds to me like you're just trying to run an existing app a specific way.

Comment: I want to run a SDL application from console, without X11. SDL can do this using the VESA driver. However I don't know how to and if it will output to multiple monitors. I can use any OS, that doesn't matter. See link in OP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/583832/how-do-i-change-the-output-monitor-for-a-text-console-in-linux-ubuntu-12-10/1328348#1328348

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out Vesa does not support multiple screen output at all.

Edit: Although I've found some sources where it is stated some graphics cards support tv-out for VESA. Is there a compatibility list for this???? One would think VESA output to external monitors is pretty critical for laptops (having broken screens, etc.)..